# Image loaded appending it to a div with jQuery - is there a callback?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this code :

```
template.find('.dynamic-content').html(
   "<img class='immagine-webcam' src='" +
    punto.Immagine + "' alt='" + punto.Titolo + "' title='" 
    + punto.Titolo + "' />"
);
```

Well: I'd like to call a function only when this image is totally loaded from server.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use the `load` method but it is deprecated and doesn't work properly with images, you can consider using a plugin like [imagesloaded](http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/)

Comment: `.load()` is deprecated? Nice to know! So, what can I use instead of .load??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onload` attribute of the `img` tag.

```
template.find('.dynamic-content').html(
   "<img class='immagine-webcam' onload='imgLoadedFun(this)' src='" +
    punto.Immagine + "' alt='" + punto.Titolo + "' title='" 
    + punto.Titolo + "' />"
);
```